# Make a shortcut that doesn't do anything

Tags: windows, windows-8, shortcuts

I need to make a shortcut (.Lnk) that doesn't do anything when clicked. Is there a way to make such a shortcut?

Comment: what is this for? For the 'blank icon' you need to make the icon transparent.  If you can't find a suitable one you could just make an .ico file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't create such shortcut in Windows,

But you can pretend that you have create a shortcut which will do nothing

for example create a Shortcut to

```
Ping.exe
```

Name this shortcut whatever you want,

when you open it, it won't do anything (just splash of Command Prompt)

And yes it's a shortcut.